# How to Add in Less Meta Informations for a Mixin Class? (phpStorm)

Tags: less, phpstorm, mixins, less-mixins

Is it possible in Less to setup mixin informations that can read phpStorm?

I write a Mixin like this:

```
.action-btn(@size: 32px, @color: #fff, @bgColor: @overlayStyleBlack, @bgColorHover: @red) {
  a {
    width: @size;
    display: block;
    color: @color;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: @size;
    background-color: @bgColor;
    &:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: @bgColorHover;
    }
  }
}
```

What i want now is, that when i use this mixin in another less file: ".action-btn();" then i want to see that i have in this Mixin 4 Settings that i can Setup. In php Classes i can do this with:

```
/**
 * @param string $xxx
 * function to check and change user is_online flag in sphinx and in mysql
 */
```

But this dont work in the Less Mixin File.

And how can i Skip some settings? Here a example to explain what i mean. (This ry dont worked)

```
.action-btn(64px, , , #fff);
```

Comment: I don't know phpStorm but you can skip some variables while calling the mixin by attaching the variable name to the value (like `.action-btn(@size:64px, @bgColorHover: #fff);`

Comment: Thanks! this work fine! =)

Comment: Please avoid puting several unrelated questions into the same ticket.

Comment: sry for this @seven-passes-max, i will dont do this again!

Comment: AFAIK IDE does not support the CssDoc (general name). Here are some tickets that you may follow (or create your own Feature Request ticket): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6 ; https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12829